# How to start an sp_procoption Stored Procedure without restarting SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to start a stored procedure that has been configured for automatic startup via `sp_procoption` without having to restart SQL Server?

Occasionally I'll need to make an adjustment and have to KILL the running session to do so, but I cannot seem to locate a way to turn it back on again without restarting SQL Server.

I've tried the most obvious options, like calling the procedure from a query window, but that's not the correct way to go about this as it requires the query to remain open.

I've searched both here and on Google to no avail. I suspect I'm not asking the right question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that the only way is the one that you're ruling out.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I suspect that, when executing from the query window, the identity is why it kills the task when the window is closed. I'm thinking if I can get it to launch under the service account that might be a solution.